# Scrape Dynamic information from html

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have dynamic information displayed in html

```
<span class="Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)"><!-- react-text: 456 -->0.5936<!-- /react-text --></span>
```

gives

> 4,000

Using python I would like to track changes in the number

I have been using beautiful soup to find the span and then the class to find the number

how can I do this every time it changes?

Answer (score 1):

If the changes are driven by javascript you will need to use something that interprets the javascript (or connects to something else that does) like [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/).

EDIT: clarification